# Translate "Strong by Choice"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

I would like to translate "Strong by Choice" to Latin as a motto for a charity. We have tried *per arbitrium fortis* but want to know if this can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Fortis* is a good word for "strong".
A harder problem is to find a good word for "choice" (or the verb "choose" if you are willing to reword a little).

*Arbitrium* means a legal judgement, a decision by an arbiter, an opinion, a decision, and similar things.
A better option would be *optio*, which means free choice and the liberty to choose.
(There is also the verb *optare*.)
Another option is *voluntas*, which is more in the direction of desire, free will, and choice.
The most appropriate tone depends on what suits your purpose.
I recommend that you compare these words in [any online Latin dictionary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).

The correct form of *fortis* depends on what it refers to.
If it refers to a single person, it is *fortis* (singular masculine or feminine).
If it refers to a group of people, use *fortes* (plural masculine or feminine).
If instead of people it refers to an institution, use *forte* (singular neuter).

The most idiomatic way to say "strong by something" is to put the something in ablative.
Using *per* is grammatical, but I find that a plain ablative gives more gravity.

Therefore my suggestion is:

> *Voluntate/optione fortis/fortes/forte*

This leaves you with six choices, depending on the exact circumstances and nuance.
The ablatives of the nouns *voluntas* and *optio* stay the same, no matter which form of *fortis* you choose.

Comment: Hi Joonas, thank you very much for your assistance. As we are a collective (an online mental health forum/community) I think that the 'fortes' would be the most appropriate form. Would that mean I would have to change the conjugation of the verb? Or is 'Voluntate fortes' grammatically correct?

Comment: @GeorgeGinger I'm glad to be able to help! In that case I agree that *fortes* is the best choice. The form *voluntate* is independent of the form of *fortes*, so *voluntate fortes* is grammatical. I just added a remark to my answer to underline this. // If you think that your question has been sufficiently answered, please mark one of the answers as accepted by clicking the little check mark on the top left corner of the answer. After getting 15 reputation points you will be able to vote up any questions and answers you like.

Answer (score 0):

"Eligimus fortis esse"; (We Choose to be Strong) fortis also means brave; powerful; resourceful: all of these fortify the effect. Possibly, a bit militaristic, for a charity; but, then, so is "Onward Christian Soldiers".

Comment: *fortes* ***?***

Comment: @Hugh: Thought about that. The concept " (to be) strong" is one concept, singular. To say "We Choose to be Strong People; then, yes, fortes.

Comment: @tony: It doesn't work like that in Italian (as well as the other Romance languages). Why would it work like that in Latin?

Comment: Vincenzo Oliva: In an anguish of indecision selected the wrong option. The human capacity for making a mistake; then, justifying it. One of the boons of this site is that errors are rapidly picked up, by colleagues, which is as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a fun supine construction: "Fortis Actu Sumus" literally meaning "We are strong with respect to doing."